# Is there a way to assign/edit String[i][j] value on runtime in dart?

Tags: string, dart

**CODE**

```
void main() {
  List<String> str = ["hello", "world"];
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < str[i].length; j++) {
      if (str[i][j] == 'o') {
        str[i][j]='e';
        print('$i,$j');
      }
    }
  }
  print(str);
}
```

**The Error I get**

```
The operator '[]=' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]=' operator.
        str[i][j]='e';
```

[image: Error Pic]

If i comment this line `//str[i][j]='e';`  i get the location of the characters but i am unable to edit the string like we usually do in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` in Dart does not have a `[]=` operator which means you cannot set a value on the `String` using the `[]` operator like you are trying to do.

This makes sense since `String` is immutable in Dart and calling the `[]=` does not allow us to return anything, so we would not be able to get the modified `String` back.

We can instead call [`.replaceRange()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/String/replaceRange.html) on the `String` which allow us to replace a part of a `String` with some other `String` value. The method will return a new `String` with the change (since we are not allowed to change any existing `String` object).

With this, we can rewrite your example to:

```
void main() {
  List<String> str = ["hello", "world"];
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < str[i].length; j++) {
      if (str[i][j] == 'o') {
        str[i] = str[i].replaceRange(j, j + 1, 'e');
        print('$i,$j');
      }
    }
  }
  print(str);
}
```

Which will output:

```
0,4
1,1
[helle, werld]
```

If the purpose is to replace all `o` with `e`, a more efficient solution would be to use the [`replaceAll()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) method:

```
void main() {
  List<String> str = ["hello", "world"];

  for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str[i] = str[i].replaceAll('o', 'e');
  }

  print(str); // [helle, werld]
}
```

Comment: TY SO MUCH. That solved my problem and now i just have to read replaceRange and other functions and then i can work with strings more efficiently

Answer (score 0):

***Simple way***: Map and replaceAll

```
 List<String> str = ["hello","world"];
  
    str = str.map((s)=> 
       s.replaceAll("o", "e")
      ).toList();

    print(str);
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Your fact about `List<String>` being "locked" is wrong. I think you are mistaken it from `const` which will make the `List` immutable including its elements.

Comment: I just prefer this way, and he just ask `Is there a way to assign/edit String[i][j] value on runtime in dart?`

Comment: If you think about it, what he tries to do is call `[]` on a `String` to change a specific letter. That is not possible in Dart. It has nothing to do with the type of `List`.

Comment: Your text is still wrong after your recent change. The core issue I have with it is, that you are misunderstanding the issue. Try use `List<String>` and you can override the `List` with a new `List` without any issues since the variable is not `final`. It does not change anything that you are using `var`.

Comment: Also "Make it a growable List." does not make any sense. The `List` is not determine to be growable by using `var` or `final`. Growable means the size of the `List` is allowed to be changed. But in your example, you are not even modifying the existing `List` but are instead creating a new one, and changes the `str` variable to point to this new `List` where the values has been changed.

Comment: And at last, your current solution expects that op wants to replace the `str` variable with a new `List` instead of modifying the existing `List` as the example provided in the question. Maybe this is correct, but you should at least explain that it is what happens in your solution.

Comment: You just explained it here, I will try.

Comment: I know, but I think the comment section here got a little too messy to expect people to actually read it :D

Comment: He might not even check it while there is down voted, but if he is curious enough, `wrong` word will attract him.

Comment: Well, your solution is not directly "wrong" any longer so I have taken my down vote back again. :)

Comment: Ty for your efforts. You did solve my problem but @julemand101 gave the best solution as now i can edit a specific part of string and not just replace all in an existing String.